Using Vapor to redirect request
I am using new to using Vapor and we want to use it as a way to alternate between a mock server and a real server.
In my client application in Xcode we may call the real-server (e.g. realbase.com/a/b/c) to get a legit response.
However we would like to do a "passthrough".  meaning the client application calls vapor, then vapor calls the real url then returns the results back to the client:

in order to make the client app use vapor we have the client make a url request to http://127.0.0.1:8080/a/b/c that way vapor will capture it.

once we get the request via app.post("a", "b", "c") {...} we want to use the real base url then make the url request to realbase.com/a/b/c then return the results back.  that way from the clients perspective  they don't know if its the real or mocked version.


At the moment this is what I wrote, but It doesn't work.  The response I get back says I'm not authorized.
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
  app.post("a", "b", "c") { req in
    let response = try await req.client.post("https://realbase.com/a/b/c") 
    return response
  }
  
}


Note Apple requires https connection. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the vapor server. Have you done that?

I guess that you also have to pass through all the headers to be authorized.
req.headers

Also you can use
app.post("**") { req in

// instead of

app.post("a", "b", "c") { req in

to catch all the endpoints and then retrieve path from the Request
req.url.path

This way you can implement passthrough server in just few lines of code.
